# Help needed with Boot Camp Setup

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition

I have a 2009 27" Core2Duo 8GB RAM iMac. The hard drive is a brand new 3TB with a fresh install of 10.8.3. I want to install Windows 7 64bit.
I set up some basic settings and have a backup at the ready. When I open Boot Camp Assisant and click Continue to the second screen I get this:

[image: Boot Camp Assistant]

There is only one partition formatted as Extended Journaled with 10.8.3 on it.
I have tried booting into recovery mode and repairing the disk. I also have done permissions and repair disk from safe mode.

What could be the issue here? I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Do you get any errors when you run Disk Utility?

Comment: I did a check in Recovery Mode on the top level drive (not the volume) and it said it fixed up a whole bunch of stuff pertaining to Windows and EFI partition. The Permissions repair did a couple of things none to do with Boot Camp and the verify turned up clean.